# Python change row values from DataFrame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

Below is my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'University':['4', '0', '3'],'Subject':['1', '2', '0']})
```

Just like 'University' & 'Subject' I have 50 other columns that end with the

column 'Score':['3', '1', '0'].

I would like to change the values for all 50 columns starting from the University all the way to Score. The condition should be if a value is => 1 then change them to 1 otherwise all other values should be zero.

I know that we are able to do it with this method:

```
df.loc[dt['University'] > 1] = 1
```

However, above I will have to type each and every one of my 50 columns. Is there a way where I could specifically mention starting from 'University' and ending at 'Score' which should include all the columns in between?

I am new to python so please try to be as clear as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just get `columns` with `df.columns`, filter out score column and iterate your method?

Comment: @VladSiv Please show me how that would work out. I am also not sure how to individually add columns in the same code. It only seems to work for 1 column at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.values >= 1, 1, 0), columns=df.columns)
```

EDIT: This is not very clean but it might do the job:

```
df.loc[:, 'University':'Score'] = df.loc[:, 'University':'Score'].apply(lambda x: (x >= 1).astype('int'))
```

EDIT2: For more conditions I would do something like this, but again I don't think this is optimal:

```
def conditions(row):
    mask1 = (row.values >= 1) & (row.values < 5)
    mask2 = (row.values >= 5) & (row.values < 10)
    mask3 = (row.values >= 10)
    
    row = mask1.astype('int') + mask2.astype('int')*2 + mask3.astype('int')*3
    return row

df.loc[:, 'University':'Score'] = df.loc[:, 'University':'Score'].apply(conditions)
```

Apply is quite slow in general, and though it might not be an issue for your case, I would probably opt to select all columns of the df and drop the ones you don't want to include in the operation and use `.loc` (instead of trying to get the range of columns).

Comment: Thank you, however, this runs over my entire dataframe, I need to do it only for specific columns. My data frame also has other columns that have strings and Boolean values which is why I only need to do it for selected columns.

The columns need to start from University and end at Score.

Comment: Thank you once again the suggestion from the final edit works. Could you also please suggest if there is a way to to multiple suggestions. For eg values >10 should be 3 value >5 but < 10 should be 2 and values >=1 but < 5 should be 1. All other values should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "University": ["4", "0", "3"],
        "Subject": ["1", "2", "0"],
        "Test1": ["1", "2", "0"],
        # Other columns
        "Score": ["3", "0", "4"],
    }
)

# Change the type, since you need int
df = df.astype(int)

for column in df.columns[:-1]:
    df.loc[df[column] > 1, column] = 1
print(df.head())
```

Which gives:

```
   University  Subject  Test1  Score
0           1        1      1      3
1           0        1      1      0
2           1        0      0      4
```

I believe that's what you want if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it does solve it however, I need to do it for specific columns and not the entire Dataframe.

Is there a way to do it starting from the University column and ending at the Score column, while including all the columns in the middle?

Comment: @AmmarKamran `df.columns` returns a list of column names. If you want to exclude first and the last element you can pass `df.columns[1:-1]`. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for more information on slice notation.

Answer (score 0):

for any number of columns except the last one `score`

```
for i in df.columns[:-1]:
    df[i]=df[i].apply(lambda x: 1 if int(x)>=1 else 0)
```